# HTML5 Filesystem not appending text to new line

Tags: html, html5-filesystem, blobstorage

I have some code as below.  I would like the string to append to the file but on a new line. as this will form a receipt of transactions for a session.

at the moment the code forms a file with text like so " Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World"  I would like the file read each hello world on a new line.

```
  function initFS() {
    window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTANT, 1024*1024,   function(filesystem) {
    fs = filesystem;
    }, errorHandler);
  }

  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#ewForm-list-fs button');
  var filelist = document.querySelector('#ewForm-list-fs-ul');

  fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: false}, function(fileEntry) {

  // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
  fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

  fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length); // Start write position at EOF.

  // Create a new Blob and write it to log.txt.
  var blob = new Blob(['Hello World'], {type: 'text/plain'});
  fileWriter.write(blob);

 }, errorHandler);

}, errorHandler);
```

Comment: What is fs?  Show that code

Comment: Try adding a new link character in the Blob contents.... 
var blob = new Blob(['Hello World' + String.fromCharCode(10)], {type: 'text/plain'});

Comment: @philNicholas.....show have thought of that thanks mate it worked.  Ill test it further and let you know 100%.